# $f ^{\prime \prime}(x) = f(x) f^{\prime \prime} (x-1) $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, functional-equations, tetration

I know the equation

$$ f^{\prime} (x) = f(x) f^{\prime} (x-1) $$

is solved by $f(x) = C$ or by tetration ( $ f(x+1) = \exp(f(x)) $).

So I wonder What are the solutions to

$$g^{\prime \prime}(x) = g(x) g^{\prime \prime} (x-1) ?$$

For $x>1$ and $g^{\prime \prime}(x) > 0$ ??

Any good asymptotics , functional equations , asymptotic functional equations or ... ???

Comment: Well, any first degree polynomial $Cx+D$ is going to work.

Comment: Any constant will work too. So $f(x)=C$

Comment: Yes but any nonpolynomial solutions ?

Comment: See Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2541892/iterations-for-g-prime-primex-gx-g-prime-primex-1